# how to setup emailjs to send email

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use mailjs to send out email, and here is what I got:

```
var server  = email.server.connect({
            user: "something@mydomain.com", 
            password: "pw", 
            host: "smtp.office365.com",
            port: "587",
            tls: true
        });
server.send({
            text: "test!!",
            from: "someemail@mydomain.com",
            to: "recipient@somedomain.com",
            subject: "hello"
        }, function(err, message){console.log(err || message);});
```

The above code eventually throw me an error:

```
{ [Error: authorization.failed]
  code: 3,
  previous: { [Error: timedout while connecting to smtp server] code: 4, smtp: undefined },
  smtp: undefined }
```

So basically my corporate email service is on office365, configured to use mydomain.com. I don't really know what does the user and password mean for the server, so I just used the sender's email and password. Is it anything wrong with my code? Maybe this is the problem?? Or otherwise what would it be?

Comment: follow tjunussov's solution in the link https://github.com/eleith/emailjs/issues/44

Answer (score 1):

First check and confirm host.Here is no need to use port: "587", tls: true.
You can use, this is wrking code

```
var server = email.server.connect({
              user: 'abc@india.com',
              password: 'vvq3tng$',
              host: 'your host',                
              ssl: true,
            });

            server.send({

              from: '<abc@india.com>', // sender address
              to: '<xyz@india.com>',// list of receivers
              cc: '',
              subject: 'your subject', // Subject line
              text: 'contant', // html body

            }, function (err, message) {

              if(err) {                        
                 console.log(err)
              } else {
               console.log("email sent")
              }
            });
```

Comment: Hello, there. How do I configure this on the client? On EmailJs website I did not see any config to set the recipient (who will receive) I can only send emails to myself